# Excel построение диаграммы из 3 столбца 200к строк

Tags: excel

Возможно ли создать диаграмму при файле с 200к строк? Если при построении excel виснет намертво.
Есть варианты?

Comment: Возможно. Но нужно ли? Диаграмма с 200к точек ничем не нагляднее графика, где только 200 точек.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее. Зачем такая детализация? Возможно, тороза не из-за диаграммы (не она первоисточник). Можно сделать динамическую диаграмму (отображение только части точек с возможностью смекщения диапазона построения)

Answer (score 1):

На одном листе Excel, если не ошибаюсь, 1 048 576 строк. Так что обработать он их сможет. Вопрос за сколько времени?

> Если при построении excel виснет намертво.

Вам обязательно строить диаграмму по всем 200к?

Даже если так, то уровень детализации для подавляющего большинства случаев будет более чем избыточна. Поэтому можно попробовать строить её не по всем точкам, а лишь по некоторым, которые позволяют в целом понять суть процесса.

Если Вы оперируете со статистикой, то её можно предварительно посчитать на листе, что также уменьшит диапазон.

Это два способа, которые приходят на ум сразу. А, вообще для таких больших объёмов данных конечно лучше использовать не Excel, а СУБД.